# git: symbol lookup error: git: undefined symbol: pcre2_maketables_free_8

Tags: kubuntu, git, 21.10

Git is not working for me after updating to Kubuntu 21.10.
When I try to execute any git commands I get the following error:
`git: symbol lookup error: git: undefined symbol: pcre2_maketables_free_8`.

I've tried reinstalling git and all libraries related to PCRE2.

My current git version: `git/impish,now 1:2.32.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]`

Any idea what could cause this and how to fix it?

Edit:
Running `ldd $(which git)` yields the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff21f00000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f27ccb5b000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f27ccb3f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f27cc917000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f27ccf62000)
```

Also, running `nm -Dg /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 | grep "pcre2_maketables_free_8"` does not return anything

Comment: Make sure that you have the required version of the lib and that `ld` can find it: `ldd $(which git)`

Comment: ldd $(which git)          
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda5793000)
 libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f341531e000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3415302000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f34150da000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3415725000)

Comment: It's better if you update your question with that information instead, so that you can apply proper formatting. Also, you only addressed one part of my comment. While you're at it, you could also run `nm -Dg <path_to_lib> | grep pcre2_maketables_free_8` as a sanity check to see if the symbol is exported.

Comment: Ran `nm -Dg /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 | grep "pcre2_maketables_free_8"` - no results were returned

Comment: As I said in my first comment, check for version compatibility between the installed versions of `git` and `libpcre2`. The symbol git is looking for isn't there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove local library and local Git, then reinstall Git with dependencies by

```
sudo rm -v $(which git)
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0*

sudo apt-get install --reinstall git libc6 libpcre2-8-0 zlib1g
```

and then retry.